# .htaccess URL rewrite not working for Ecwid product link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I used the third party cart system from Ecwid.  When I click on any prouduct, it shows this link or URL:

```
http://www.bestsports.ca/product.php#!/~/product/category=9414048&id=11484861
```

How can I rewrite this URL instead of showing category id?  I want to show the product name. I already tried your above instruction but its not working.  Can you please explain is it possible to make this URL into this SEO friendly URL?

```
http://www.bestsports.ca/MMAGEAR/productname/
```

I want so show first URL like above URL.

Comment: You say "your above instructions".   Where are these instructions that you followed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for .htaccess to rewrite URLs with a  hash (`#`) symbol in them.   That is because everything after the hash is considered a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri).   The purpose of the fragment identifier is to specify the content to be show within the HTML document.    It may be handled:

- By the browser by scrolling to the correct place in the page
- By JavaScript by loading and displaying the specified content

In your case, it appears to specify the AJAX content to be displayed.  That is handled client side by JavaScript.

The hash and everything after it **are not even sent to your server**.   They are client side *only*.  Because of this, there is no possibility for your server to rewrite a URL based on the information after the hash.  *.htaccess* can't even get this information.

The only way for you to rewrite these URLs would be to modify the JavaScript in the page to have it change the `document.location` to the URL of your choice.